# eroor 1004, cells function with variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a quick game in Excel VBA, in a userform and a button should use a value from a cell that I input with variable but everytime I got the error 1004.

The weird thing is that when I put a normal number instead of the second variable. the error doesn't appear.

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()
Dim types(2 To 19, 2 To 19, 2 To 19, 2 To 19), ataques(2 To 19, 2 To 19, 2 To 19) As Double

Dim tipo12, tipo21, tipo22, ataque11, ataque12, ataque13, ataque14, ataque21, ataque22, taque23, ataque24 As Integer
Dim tipo11 As Integer

Dim ataq1a2 As Integer

tipo11 = Label19.Caption
tipo12 = Label20.Caption
tipo21 = Label21.Caption
tipo22 = Label22.Caption
ataque11 = Label23.Caption
ataque12 = Label24.Caption
ataque13 = Label25.Caption
ataque14 = Label26.Caption
ataque21 = Label27.Caption
ataque22 = Label28.Caption
ataque23 = Label29.Caption
ataque24 = Label30.Caption

MsgBox tipo21

'MsgBox Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(2, 2).Value
MsgBox Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(tipo11, tipo21).Value
End Sub`
```

Comment: I meant by editing the tags. I edited them for you.

Comment: Which line throws the error? You have declared `tipo12-taque23` as `Variant`, `Caption` is usually a string, so at least `tipo21` could be a string which would throw an error. Before the `MsgBox`, try checking with `Debug.Print VarType(tipo21)`.

Comment: ^^^ `Dim tipo12, tipo21, tipo22, ataque11, ataque12, ataque13, ataque14, ataque21, ataque22, taque23, ataque24 As Integer` - only `ataque24` is an `Integer` and the rest are `Variant`. Then, you may need a `CLng` here to cast the string to a `Long`.

Comment: i solve it now, i didnt know all the other variables were  variant. the error was in 
MsgBox Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(tipo11, tipo21).Value because of the variables being variant not  integer